# Magento CSP: style-src missing from response header

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, csp, magento2.3.7

We have added

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

to the `etc/csp_whitelist.xml` of a module within `app/code/`, in order to allow externally included fonts via TypeKit on the site. However, the resulting `content-security-policy-report-only` response header does not contain `style-src` at all. Even though not just our module defines something for the `style-src` policy, there are in fact a few Magento core modules, that would actually add their own `style-src` policy. But they do not show up at all in the response generated by Magento. The current content of that response header only looks like this:

```
font-src *.fontawesome.com *.yotpo.com *.googleapis.com *.gstatic.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net *.yotpo.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcom…merce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com api.comapi.com webchat.dotdigital.com *.yotpo.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; child-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; base-uri 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
```

Are there any additional steps necessary, to enable `style-src` for CSP?

- Magento `2.3.7`

Comment: Are there any additional steps necessary, to enable style-src for CSP? -> *No*

Answer (score 0):

take look below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="zipmoney" type="host">*.zipmoney.com.au</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="zipmoney" type="host">*.zipmoney.com.au</value>

            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="klarna-base" type="host">*.klarna.com</value>
                <value id="googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="vimeocdn" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
                <value id="youtube-img" type="host">*.ytimg.com</value>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
                <value id="lightemporium" type="host">*.lightemporium.com</value>                
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
                <value id="zipmoney" type="host">*.zipmoney.com.au</value>

            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="zipmoney" type="host">*.zipmoney.com.au</value>

            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="zipmoney" type="host">*.zipmoney.com.au</value>

            </values>
        </policy>
        
        <policy id="frame-src">
            <values>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        
        <policy id="form-action">
            <values>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Comment: Yours is not different from mine though (apart from having more).

Comment: yes, just for synax knowledge I added more.. no extra step required.. just clear cache after adding in xml

Comment: Yes, but my point is that this did not work. And as I pointed out, some core modules from magento already add `style-src` content security policies, but they do not show up in the response header either.

Comment: where you added file ? give full path

Comment: `app/code/InspiredMinds/Webshop/etc/csp_whitelist.xml` (that's our own `InspiredMinds_Webshop` module for this Magento instance).